# How to import large CSV file in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a large CSV file and want to import it very quickly in the SQL table using VBScript.

I have tried with `Bulk Insert` statement to import all rows in the table but found the following issues:

1. The file contains greater or fewer columns than the table.
2. I have mapping stored in the database between the file's fields and database table's fields.
3. In the file, columns are in a different order.

Is there an alternative way to import a large CSV file using VBScript?

Comment: What makes you think VBScript will be easier than bulk insert?

Comment: `BULK INSERT` the data into a staging table first then, then transform the data from the staging table to the production table.

Comment: @Lankymart, because I have a dynamic mapping stored in database and want to insert based on file's fields mapped with SQL table fields.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a very large csv file into an existing SQL Server table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20989266)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing big csv file with too many columns into a table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56047688)